GetType не работает с out параметром
Я написал этот код и он не работает. Я понимаю, почему, но как мне его исправить?
internal class ViewProperty<T> : IViewProperty<T>
{
  protected Dictionary<Type, object> PropetriesStorage { get; } = new();

  public bool TryGetProperty<PropType, SubType>(out PropType _property) where PropType : IViewProperty<SubType>
  {
    bool result = PropetriesStorage.TryGetValue(_property.GetType(), out var temp);
    Trace.Assert(temp is PropType);
    _property = (PropType)temp;
    return result;
  }
}

Возникает ошибка "CS0269    Использование выходного параметра "_property", которому не присвоено значение."
Разве параметр (пусть даже не инициализированный) не содержит тип в момент вызова?

А, ну естественно, как вы можете взять _property.GetType(), если в _property на тот момент ничего нет ещё. Не очень понятно, чего вы вообще добиваетесь этим кодом.

@CrazyElf а на что похоже?

Просто если у вас предполагаются разные типы, то нужно использовать универсальные типы и т.п. Выходной параметр тоже может быть универсальным, также как и входной. Толковую прямо ссылку я что-то не нашёл, но что-то типа того https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier Сейчас у вас тип выходной переменной жёстко прошит, поэтому в определении типа этой переменной "на ходу" нет никакого смысла, он всегда будет одинаковый. А вот при использовании <T, R> или как оно там пишется, вы сможете эти буковки использовать.

@CrazyElf спасибо за рекомендацию, подправил ответ

Обязательно присвойте значение параметрам outв вызываемом методе перед доступом к значению ошибка CS0269
Вы пытаетесь получить тип _property с помощью метода .GetType(). Но ведь на момент вызова этого метода переменная _property еще не инициализирована
Предложу использование typeof(PropType)
typeof(PropType) возвращает объект типа Type, представляющий тип PropType, который является обобщенным параметром метода, работает корректно, так как PropType уже определён на этапе компиляции и не зависит от значения переменной
Мое исправление заключается в замене обращения к GetType() неинициализированной переменной на безопасное обращение к типу через typeof(PropType), что устранило проблему компиляции и сохранило логику работы метода
class ViewProperty<T> : IViewProperty<T>
{
    protected Dictionary<Type, object> PropetriesStorage { get; } = new();

    public bool TryGetProperty<PropType, SubType>(out PropType _property) where PropType : IViewProperty<SubType>
    {
        bool result = PropetriesStorage.TryGetValue(typeof(PropType), out var temp);
        if (temp is PropType prop)
        {
            _property = prop;
            return result;
        }

        _property = default;
        return false;
    }

    public void AddProperty<PropType>(PropType property) where PropType : class
    {
        PropetriesStorage[typeof(PropType)] = property;
    }
}


Я использовал это:
public bool TryGetProperty<SubType>([NotNullWhen(true)] out IViewProperty<PropType>? _property)
{
  if (PropetriesStorage.TryGetValue(typeof(PropType), out var temp))
  {
    _property = (PropType)temp;
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    _property = default;
    return false;
  }
}


@aepot Так то там typeof(PropType) теперь вместо _property.GetType(), но чтобы это увидеть, нужно тратить время, это реально неудобно.

Я добавлю отметку об изменениях в ответ

Вообще решение получше есть https://pastebin.com/gMMLyXLh, и непонятно, зачем Trace.Assert если буквально на следующей строке будет InvalidCastExeption в случае ошибки типа.

@aepot я хотел убрать предупреждение компилятора привычным образом : )

Кстати, из-за исключения фактически этот метод никогда не сможет вернуть false. Стоит подумать над улушчение его логики. Хотя может я ошибаюсь и null успешно кастанётся, но не уверен, надо тестить.

@aepot а, точно подмечено... Сейчас исправлю

https://pastebin.com/bRCdaU8f быть может вот так?

@aepot почему бы не оформить ваш код в качестве ответа, чтобы его было удобно просматривать участникам StackOverflow?

Я не уверен, что это решение вам подойдёт, так как не знаю требований к нему.

@aepot так вы опубликуйте и узнаете)

@aepot почему вы удалили ваш ответ?

А зачем он, если уже есть другое решение, которое вам подошло. Хотя у меня к нему есть тоже вопросы, но уж не буду ничего писать.

Мне кажется, в полученной логике TryGetProperty это несовсем оптимальное решение. Я бы посмотрел в сторону GetPropertyOrDefault не возвращаяя bool, а просто возвращать null если неудача или в словаре сохранён неверный тип.

@aepot звучит здраво
